# Prototyping Interactive Forms - Fill in the Blank

Tags: forms

Can anyone recommend a form prototyping tool (a la Typeform, or Google forms, etc.), that can present questions in the form of "fill-in-the-blank."

I want to be able to present the user with a sentence where part of it is missing, and the blank is actually a text entry field they can complete. I am looking for something similar to how it's done here: https://www.hioscar.com/get-quote/

Any suggestions?

Comment: a bit more info. This kind of form is often referred to as either a "mad libs" form or a "natural language" form, as per this blog post: https://www.jroehm.com/2014/01/ui-pattern-natural-language-form/

Comment: Is there a reason you need a builder instead of just writing it yourself? If you're comfortable modifying HTML there's codrops: https://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/05/21/natural-language-form-with-custom-input-elements/

Comment: the idea is to be able to prototype these kinds of prompts quickly. The code in the link you provided seems simple enough to adjust to demonstrate a concept, but I guess what I'm ultimately after is a specialized tool for this kind of interface.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at https://www.jotform.com.

Here is a guide where the author is using jotforms to create a fill-in-the-blanks form similar to what you want :-

https://zapier.com/blog/fill-in-the-blank-form/

Answer (score 0):

```
    form action="" id="usrform">
what is your name? <input type="text" name="name">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

The question and input must be on the same line, then add css to remove input background, remove `border` input and add `border-bottom color` to the input. i think you know the css.